# Core Data: Synchronizing the ManagedObjectContext on the Main thread with a newly spawned thread

Tags: core-data, ios5

I have a multi-threaded iOS App with a background thread that synchronizes data with the Cloud. I have read several questions regarding merging changes from a background thread to the main thread.

However, what I need to do is the opposite. I somehow need to make sure that a newly spawned background thread picks up data that was newly created within the moc of the main thread. Right before spawning the thread. For some reason, some data added to the main thread's poc even after a save does not show up in the moc of the new thread. I am definitely missing something while spawining the thread and its moc.

btw: I have a moc per thread and a shared persistent store coordinator.

Here is the code that sets up the moc per thread:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *) storageContext

NSThread *currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [currentThread.threadDictionary objectForKey:@"context"];
if(context != nil)
{
    return context;
}

context = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator: self.coordinator];

[currentThread.threadDictionary setObject:context forKey:@"context"];

return context;
```

And here is the code that spawns the thread

```
-(void)startBackgroundSync

AutoSync *target = [AutoSync withInit];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:target selector:@selector(sync) object:nil];   
operation = [operation autorelease];

//Add the operation to the queue
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

A nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Sohil